# Case insensitive search without using a function in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hana, case-sensitive

Any way to make a case insensitive without using a function in the where clause?
Please specify the database you are talking about when/if you reply.  I am aware that MySQL is already case insensitive by default.  What about Oracle or MSSQL or HANA?

```
select * from mytable WHERE upper(fieldname) = 'VALUE'
```

Comment: If your target database (you never told us which one you are actually using) does not support this behavior, you can always maintain a separate column containing the case insensitive version of the original column.

Comment: Well, for each rdbms it is different - using `collate` line in Wanderer's answer is for SQL Server, using `SET NLS_COMP` is for Oracle, and for Sap Hana it might be an entirely different thing.

Comment: The `upper(columnname) = 'VALUE'` will work with practically any dbms. However, don't expect index usage always, so performance may be really poor.

Comment: I think a question asking about 4 databases is too broad.

Comment: Agree with with @GordonLinoff that the question seems too broad to yield one best answer. Also, the important motivation behind the question seems to be that solutions should still allow index usage by the RDBMS. That should be part of the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 12c answer

```
select * from mytable WHERE fieldname='Value' collate binary_ci
```

SAP HANA does not seem to have a way other than using upper or lower.

SQL Server and MySQL do not distinguish between upper and lower case letters—they are case-insensitive by default.

Answer (score 4):

**[`collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.

Default Collation is *`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`* which is *`case insensitive`*. And if we need to make it case sensitive, then adding *`COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`* makes the search case sensitive.

**Query**

```
select * from [mytable] 
where [fieldname] = 'VALUE' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

**[`Find a demo here`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/887094/case-insensitive-search-without-using-a-function-in-the-where-clause#resultSets)**

Comment: Is this for MS SQL Server, Hana or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh : `MS SQL Server`

Comment: I am looking for how to do this in mssql, oracle, and hana.  I want to understand how.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is tagged Oracle, I will provide a solution which works in Oracle.

You can set these session parameters for case insensitive searching

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_COMP=ANSI;
SQL> alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI; 
SQL> select 1 from DUAL where 'abc' = 'ABC';

         1
----------
         1
```

Read more at  [**Linguistic Sorting and String Searching**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005)

as @mathguy points out,

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
```

is more common than using ANSI

Comment: I would add: _CI means "case insensitive"; NLS_COMP must also be (re)set, the default is BINARY and it should be reset to LINGUISTIC (ANSI works too, but LINGUISTIC is more common). Also, as a matter of style, it is probably better to enclose the values in single quotes, although Oracle allows BINARY_CI and such to appear without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Making the column upper (or lower) case as you are showing in order to compare it, is the standard way of making a case insensitive comparision. (`UPPER` and `LOWER` are functions defined in the SQL standard.)

If you don't want to apply a function on the column, then you can of course write a recursive query to generate all upper/lower case permutations of the value ('VALUE', 'vALUE', 'VaLUE', ..., 'value') and check whether your column value is in this set. Standard SQL provides the `SUBSTRING` function for accessing substrings (e.g. the nth letter) and `CHAR_LENGTH` for getting the string's length.

It depends on the DBMS you are using and its version to what extent the standard is supported. In Oracle for example it's `SUBSTR` instead of `SUBSTRING` and `LENGTH` instead of `CHAR_LENGTH`. MySQL on the other hand features both  `SUBSTRING` and `CHAR_LENGTH` directly, but only supports recursive queries as of version 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (column_name, 'value', 'i');
```

Comment: the problem with this query is that you now have regexp_like as the function in the where clause.  If you are querying a huge table that function has to run on every row.  My goal is to get rid of functions in the where clause.

Comment: but why you want to get rid of function in where clause .will it cause any problem if it will be a large table.

Comment: using functions in the where clause is generally not a good idea because it invalidates the index.  (unless you have indexed the function also).

Comment: Even if you avoid the WHERE clause, changing the comparison logic often makes Index access impossible. 
E.g. on Oracle the changed NLS settings would require additional indexes that have been created with these settings. See e.g. https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/introduction-to-linguistic-indexes-part-i/

Answer (score 0):

One could use CONTAINS Function. For example, Microsoft SQL Server query:

```sql
SELECT    * 
FROM      TableName 
WHERE     ColumnName LIKE 'Abc%'
```

Maybe written in SAP HANA as:

```sql
SELECT    * 
FROM      TableName 
WHERE     CONTAINS(ColumnName,'Abc%');
```

https://help.sap.com/viewer/05c9edaee7fe4d28ab3627d0b1583df6/2021_01_QRC/en-US/b45ff4c0e9ab4ba7a9e18a2552adeb3d.html